# Adding multiple remote repository to a single local repository

Tags: git, github, bitbucket

I pushed to GitHub a local repo with following command:
`git remote add origin <HTTPS-GitHub-URL>`

Then I wanted to push the same local repo to BitBucket so it made sense to me to add another remote path so I ran: `git remote add origin <HTTPS-BitBucket-URL>` but this does not work so I had to change `origin` to `origin1` and then it worked.

So, how can I treat both remote repos as the same (e.g. not changing name)?

Answer (score 0):

Having remote `origin` pointing to github, try this:

```
$> git config --add remote.origin.url <HTTPS-BitBucket-URL>
```

And then push it with:

```
$> git push origin
```

Comment: Thanks but won't this change the url on the origin?

Comment: Why don't you just try?